# Unable to ingest 'int' values into a 'bigint' column while loading data into an Azure Synapse table using pyspark in Azure Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I recently altered the datatype of a column from int to bigint in Azure Synapse due to the incoming data containing larger values. But when I'm trying to perform some new loads, I now get the below error:

```
Underlying SQLException(s):
  - com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: HdfsBridge::recordReaderFillBuffer - Unexpected error encountered filling record reader buffer: ClassCastException: class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class java.lang.Long (java.lang.Integer and java.lang.Long are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap') [ErrorCode = 106000] [SQLState = S0001]
```

I was surprised by this error because ideally the `int` values should automatically be compatible in a `bigint` column. But apparently pyspark doesn't seem to think so. I don't know why.

I also check the current setting of the below spark configurations in my databricks cluster:

```
spark.conf.get("spark.sql.storeAssignmentPolicy") #outputs: 'Legacy'
spark.sql.ansi.enabled #outputs: 'false'
```

However, when I manually performed an insertion using INSERT INTO query in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) with one sample record using an `int` value for my `bigint` column in Azure Synapse, it successfully inserted it.

So, something sees to be going wrong when doing this with `df.write()`from Databricks. I'm not sure where the things are going wrong and what I can do to correct them.

Any help, please?

Comment: what about casting the necessary column into the `long` ?

Comment: The problem is that the code base is large and generic for hundreds of tables. And the issue is taking place with one table where the datatype has been recently updated. So there is no way to identify this one column among the whole and the cast it into `Long`. So, I'm wondering if this has to do with some kinda pyspark configuration or something.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution to this is to cast the integer columns in the data frame to long before writing to the database.

For example, define your data frame, using the `cast() function`.

> **If you want to change a single column to cast the integer into long:**

**Here is the code:**

```
df1 = df.withColumn("id", col("id").cast("long"))
```

[image]

> **Here is the code for Multiple column cast:**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df = df.select([col(c).cast('long') if t == 'int'  else col(c) for c, t in df.dtypes])
```

[image]

**Or**

You can Iterate all columns in the data frame schema using a for loop.

**Sample code:**

```
for field in df.schema.fields:
    if  isinstance(field.dataType, IntegerType):
        df = df.withColumn(field.name, col(field.name).cast(LongType()))
```

[image]